# Error parsing alert "expr" with regular expression in it

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to define an alert rule with "**expr**" containing regular-expression

```
Metric: XYZ-POST-failure-400-1min-rate

- alert: alert_name_here
  expr: __name__=~"(.*)-POST-failure-\d{3}-1min-rate" > 0
```

Unit testing this using "**promtool**"

```
Error
group "group_name", rule 1, "alert_name_here": could not parse expression: parse error at char 10: unexpected character after '=': '~'
```

Is this even supported by Prometheus alert manager?
Can someone guide me on what is the correct way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: You are missing the brackets `{__name__=~...}` for matching any metric of name matching the regex; this is actually a label matching expression.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. But including brackets {} will make the YAML invalid

Comment: Quote the expression to interpret it as a string : `'{__name__=~"..."} > 0'`

Answer (score 4):

The expression should be a valid PromQL query, you are missing the curly braces to make it a [valid vector selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors):

```
{__name__=~"(.*)-POST-failure-\d{3}-1min-rate"} > 0
```

You can test it in your Prometheus interface.

Regarding the YAML issue of having a leading curly brace, you can use single quotes for which the special character sequences are allowed:

```
- alert: alert_name_here
  expr: '{__name__=~"(.*)-POST-failure-\d{3}-1min-rate"} > 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error when I twisted the `=~` with `~=`.

```
parse error: unexpected character inside braces: '~'
```

This kind of errors are hard to spot and the error message is not that helpful.